# Python 3.7 Class Property Returns Object

Tags: python, class, object, properties

I am trying to create a class with properties.  Every time I access the property, no matter how I try, I get `<property object at xxx>`.  I am running version 3.7.8 in Visual Studio Community 2019.  Here are all the different ways I have tried:

```
class Form(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._text="New Form test"

    #----------------------------------------------------------
    #example 1
    @property
    def Text(self):
        return _text
    
    @Text.getter
    def get_text(self):
        return self._text

    @Text.setter
    def set_text(self,value):
        self._text=value
    #----------------------------------------------------------
    #example 2
    def get_text(self):
        return self._text

    Text = property(get_text)
    #----------------------------------------------------------
    #example 3
    @property
    def Text(self):
        return self._text
    #----------------------------------------------------------
    #example 4
    @property
    def Text(self):
        return "foo.bar"
    #----------------------------------------------------------
    #example 5
    def get_text(self):
        return self._text

    def set_text(self,value):
        self._text=value

    Text=property()
    Text.getter(get_text)
    Text.setter(set_text)
    #----------------------------------------------------------
    #example 6
    def get_text(self):
        return self._text

    def set_text(self,value):
        self._text=value
    
    Text = property(get_text,set_text)
    #----------------------------------------------------------
```

I added labels for each example and added #6 and an other way I tried based on one answer given.  I also changed Form(object): to Form: with no change.

Comment: Wrt _"no matter how I try"_ - show the code you're using to create an instance of your class and access & set those properties; as I've done [in my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66355033/1431750). Ex `f = Form() ...` what else are you executing?

Comment: import Form

global _form
_form=Form.Form
    lbl=Entry(designFormTitlebar)
    lbl.configure(fg="white",font="Arial 10 bold",background="blue2")
    lbl.insert(0,_form.Text)
    lbl.place(x=5,y=5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do it the way as [described in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property). The method decorated by just `@property` is already the getter, so you don't need to create another getter method. And for the setter, the method name needs to be the same as the property name:

```py
class Form:
    def __init__(self):
        self._text = "New Form test"

    @property
    def Text(self):
        return self._text
    
    @Text.setter
    def Text(self, value):
        self._text = value


f = Form()
f.Text
# output: 'New Form test'
f.Text = 'other text'
f.Text
# output: 'other text'
```

Btw, classes in Python3 don't need to inherit from `object`.

Other versions:

```py
# works, only a getter
def get_text(self):
    return self._text

Text = property(get_text)
```

```py
# works, only a getter
@property
def Text(self):
    return self._text
```

```py
# works, only a getter which returns 'foo.bar'
@property
def Text(self):
    return "foo.bar"
```

For the last version, when you use the `Text = property(...)` long form, the getter & setter have to be declared together:

```py
def get_text(self):
    return self._text

def set_text(self, value):
    self._text = value

Text = property(get_text, set_text)
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific on your comment of "Why not do it the way as described in the docs"?  According to the docs there are three different ways to write the code and in my examples you will see I tried those different ways and more.  I even tried copy and paste your code into my class and it still gives me the object back and not the text.  I also tried removing the inheritance of object with no change.

Comment: There's a minor variation in some of your trials - if the variation wasn't there, your code would have worked. In fact, only the first and last variation had something to fix. The other 3 were fine. And this is standard Python, no modules, no imports. So if it's not working on VSCommunity - check if it works in a regular Python script executed from the command line. And `example 6` in your current version of the question is what I have above - which works. So again, your install may be **seriously broken** if it's not working for you.

Comment: The code runs outside of VS with no change.

Comment: I got my Rasp Pi running and ran the code there.  It still shows property object and not the text value.  So it cant be the python install on my pc.

Comment: I edited the code to be as simple as possible and I get the same results.
import Form

def main():
    global _form
    _form=Form.Form
    print(_form.Text)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Comment: You're creating it as `_form=Form.Form` which doesn't create an instance of the class, just makes a reference to it. **Do `_form=Form.Form()` to actually create an instance** of that class - note the parentheses `()`. That's why it's important for the question to include the code you're executing to use the class.